# How do I integrate this equation with respect to $dcos\theta$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have this equation:
$$\int_0^{-1}\big[(1+\cos^2\theta)+\cos\theta\big]d\cos\theta$$

I tried to do a u substitution. However, this didn't work. How can I evaluate this integral?

Edit: Also attempted to use Wolfram Alpha. It didn't recognize that I wanted to use $d\cos\theta$ and not $d\theta$.

Comment: @zwim I have looked deeper into Riemann - Stieltjes integration and I must admit that I jumped into this too quickly. I was entirely unaware of the topic and I had created a misleading response. Thank you for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be a [Riemann–Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral). Because $\cos(\theta)$ is continuously differentiable, we have that
$$\int_0^{-1}\left[(1+\cos^2\theta)+\cos\theta\right]\mathrm{d}\cos\theta=\int_0^{-1}\left[(1+\cos^2\theta)+\cos\theta\right]\frac{\mathrm{d}\cos\theta}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta$$

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out by @Botond and reinforced by @zwim , this is an example of a Riemann-Stieltjes integral which takes the form

$$\int_a^bf(\theta) \ dg(\theta)$$

In this case, the variable is $\theta$, $f(\theta)=1+ \cos^2(\theta)+\cos\theta$, and $g(\theta)=\cos\theta$

As Botond pointed out,

$$\int_a^bf(\theta) \ dg(\theta) = \int_a^bf(\theta)g'(\theta) \ d\theta$$

Thus, for your specific example, we have

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{-1}[1+ \cos^2(\theta)+\cos\theta] \ d\cos(\theta)&=-\int_0^{-1}\sin(\theta)[1+ \cos^2(\theta)+\cos(\theta)] \ d\theta
\\
&=-\int_0^{-1}[\sin(\theta) + \sin(\theta) \cos^2(\theta)+\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)] \ d\theta
\\
&=\cos(\theta)\Bigg|_0^{-1} + \dfrac{1}{3}\cos^3(\theta)\Bigg|_0^{-1}+ \dfrac{1}{2}\cos^2(\theta)\Bigg|_0^{-1}
\\
&=\cos(-1) + \dfrac{1}{3}\cos^3(-1)+ \dfrac{1}{2}\cos^2(-1) - 1 - \dfrac{1}{3} - \dfrac{1}{2}
\\
&=\cos(-1) + \dfrac{1}{3}\cos^3(-1)+ \dfrac{1}{2}\cos^2(-1) - \dfrac{11}{6}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Your deleted answer was partially correct. It is used the integration method of substitution: $x=\cos \theta$. You must have adjusted the limits of integral: $\int_0^{-1} [1+\cos^2 \theta+\cos \theta] d\cos \theta=\int_\color{red}{1}^\color{red}{{\cos (-1)}} [1+x^2+x]dx$.